# Open file Using Win::OLE without Office

Tags: perl, win32ole

I'm using [`Win32::OLE`](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32::OLE) for parsing an the Excel file. I can't use Microsoft Office on my machine so I installed Excel Viewer.

Following is the code that I'm using to init the OLE

```
my $Excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application') or die "oops\n";
```

Kindly suggest some way around this. How can I `new()` it through Excel Viewer?

Comment: Depending on what special attributes you need to examine, it may be sufficient to export the file in CSV format and write your Perl program to process that using [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV)

Comment: I'm parsing Excel files. I can't do things manually.

Comment: @Bordin: to be specific, parsing .xls, .xlsx files.

Comment: Open Office has an OLE API. Are you able to install that?

Comment: It amazes me what restrictions some programmers put up with. “I have to write a program to save the world using Perl,” they say, “but I'm not allowed to use a keyboard.”

Comment: @Borodin I'have installed Win32::OLE for perl. I have installed Open Office, but do not have any idea for OLE API.

Comment: Have you perhaps tried Googling *"Open Office OLE API"*?

Comment: @Borodin I did, but the languages from which I can use OpenOffice.org are c++ and java. I'm new to perl, if you can explain it in detail, it will be really helpful for me. Kindly look for my actual problem mentioned in the below comment.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel Viewer can't be scripted/automated. Depending on what you really want to do, your options are:

1. Use [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~dougw/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65/)
2. Use [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (perhaps via DBI)
3. (Install and) use [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/)/[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) if you need more than data access. See [OODoc](http://search.cpan.org/~jmgdoc/OpenOffice-OODoc/).

Comment: can i use Win32::OLE after installing OpenOffice?

Comment: @Ankul - yes, but see e.g. https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=66795 to get a feeling for the differences between the scripting interfaces. You should publish you real world tasks with some details to get more specific answers.

Comment: I'm converting Excel .xls,.xlsx files to .csv files.Since a file contains~10k lines memoryoutofbound error comes on command prompt,but I figured out to resolve this using cell_handler. But for few excel files cell handler skips the last row of the excel files which contain tables.But adding a row in the end of file resolves the problem. In order to make it work have to append new row in the end.Using OLE currently but as on our production system MSOffice will not be installed.So I want to use some other option for this, using OLE without changing my script much.